# Call count of static variable initialization inside static functions & methods

Tags: c++

I have **counter.h**:

```
static int count() {
    static int counter = 0; // called anew in each translation unit
    return ++counter;
}
```

and **Singleton.h**:

```
class Singleton
{
public:
    Singleton(const Singleton& other) = delete;
    Singleton& operator = (const Singleton& other) = delete;

    static Singleton& instance()
    {
        static Singleton ret; // called only once
        return ret;
    }

private:
    Singleton() { std::cout << "call\n"; }
};
```

and **foo.cpp**:

```
void foo()
{
    count();
    auto& db = Singleton::instance();
}
```

**zoo.cpp**:

```
void zoo()
{
    count();
    auto& db = Singleton::instance();
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
int main()
{
    foo();
    zoo();

    return 0;
}
```

---

Why the line `static int counter = 0;` called twice but the line `static Singleton ret;` only once?

Comment: `static` used for a global function (like `static int count()`) means it is used per translation unit. So each translation unit will have a copy of `count()` with all its content (including the static variable `counter`). On the other hand `static` for a class method means something else (that it is not bound to an instance).

Comment: The `static` keyword is one of the most ambiguous in the C++ language. It's meaning when used on a class member is very different from when used in its 'old C' form.

Comment: how do you know it is called only once? Even if it was called twice the function `count` would always return `0`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number via a debugger + actual `count()` code contains `++counter` line

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `int count()` is declared `static`, as such it gets *internal linkage*, meaning there's a separate copy of the function created in each translation unit in which it is used.

If you want a single `count()` function in the application, don't declare it `static` so that it gets *external linkage* (and move the definition to a .cpp file), **or** simply declare it `inline`.

```
inline int count() {
    static int counter = 0;
    return counter;
}
```

This is different from a `static` class member. Class members, including `static` ones, get the same linkage as the class they belong to (which in your case has external linkage).